# How to handle question having multiple different duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I'm wondering about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477524/sending-email-in-aspnet-identity-system) question. Where OP has asked for multiple questions at once!

And that all questions having separate duplicate question.

> The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context
>   Possible duplicate: [Server.MapPath does not exist in current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122119/server-mappath-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

---

> The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context 
>   Possible duplicate: [Why the name 'Request' does not exist when writing in a class.cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439709/why-the-name-request-does-not-exist-when-writing-in-a-class-cs-file)

---

> 'Url' does not contain a definition for 'Action'
>   Possible duplicate: [Generating absolute url to action from within Api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740894/generating-absolute-url-to-action-from-within-api-controller)

How to handle such question, which has multiple different duplicate question?

Comment: *Might* be a good candidate for "Too Broad" instead...

Comment: @Makoto: I'm wondring.. "Too Broad" is for *either too many possible answers* and here too many possible duplicate questions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general if question can easily be answered by several distinct duplicates - downvote and consider to close as "too broad" or "missing MCVE" like in this case.

If you decided not to vote to close - (i.e. it in not so obvious to find duplicates) - write answer stitching links to "duplicates" together into answer to concrete question.

Answer (score 6):

For a few years now, gold badge holders have been able to edit the duplicate list to add up to 5 dups.  If there are only a couple separate problems that don't interact with each other in a way that needs more than a comment to explain, we can do that.

But at some point the interaction of things might justify an answer that stitches them together, especially if some of the things are non-trivial in the first place.  (Not well-known FAQs.)

Comment: Screenshot of the Question for <10k as it's "now" (2022) been deleted...? // + Title of this current Question doesn't make sense grammatically... ("multiple" = plural) + again in the Body. // + Ugly Typo also in the other Answer that could be corrected...